# Extract number of votes from poll tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

```
create table `polls`(
`pollid` smallint unsigned not null auto_increment,
`question` varchar(40) not null,
`answer1` varchar(30) not null,
`answer2` varchar(30) not null,
`answer3` varchar(30) default null,
`answer4` varchar(30) default null,
`answer5` varchar(30) default null,
primary key(`pollid`)
);

create table `poll_votes`(
`void` mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
`pollid` smallint unsigned not null,
`ip_address` varchar(15) not null,
`answer` tinyint unsigned not null,
primary key(`void`),
foreign key(`pollid`) references `polls`(`pollid`)
);
```

In poll_votes.answer I store the integer 1-5, which answer the user has voted.

I want to use a single query to retrieve in a row the count of votes of all 5 answers.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2) consider whether your schema design is optimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_5
FROM poll_votes;
```

To get these summary stats for each `pollid`, then use:

```
SELECT
    pollid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_5
FROM poll_votes
GROUP BY
    pollid;
```

Comment: If I add pollid to select statement to get which poll I'm viewing the results, I receive this error: `Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'poll_votes.pollid'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` This because in polls there are more than one record.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use for one pollid
try this

```
    SELECT
    pollid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN answer = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_answer_5
FROM poll_votes WHERE pollid = 1
GROUP BY
    pollid
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a very convenient short-hand notation for such counting:

```
SELECT SUM(answer = 1) AS num_answer_1,
       SUM(answer = 2) AS num_answer_2,
       SUM(answer = 3) AS num_answer_3,
       SUM(answer = 4) AS num_answer_4,
       SUM(answer = 5) AS num_answer_5
FROM poll_votes;
```

That is, boolean values are treated as numbers in an arithmetic context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.